# Equilibrium of differential mass element of a homogeneous rod hanging from ceiling

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, equilibrium

I was solving a question that asked me to find the change in length of a rod when it is hung from the ceiling. When I saw the solution, they took some differential elements and said that a force due to the mass of the rod below the element would cause the extension and they integrated it but I had done the opposite. I took differential element but thought that the mass of the rod above the element will be compressing it and even the answer was the same.

This also made me question another thing If I take a differential element in the rod and since it is in equilibrium then the mass of the upper part(shown in blue) should be equal to the mass of the part below it(shown in green) but since the rod is homogeneous it is clearly visible that it is not.
Why is it so?

[image]

Comment: When the solution, considering expansion of volume elements, and your calculation, considering compression of volume elements, yield the same result, there is something severely wrong. For starters, just check whether the proposed solution is longer or shorter than the equilibrium length of the rod to see which solution has a chance of being right.

Comment: Also, if the rod is hanging from the ceiling, where is the compression coming from? Especially for the lowest volume element. You cannot compress it with a free boundary at the bottom end. Gravitation is pulling it down, the rod above it is pulling it up - such that there can be equilibrium - where in the world would a compression come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...but thought that the mass of rod above the element will be
> compressing it...

It is not. But that would be the case if the bar was resting in the floor, instead of hanging from the ceiling. The situation is symmetric, so its expected to reach the same differential equation.

> since it is in equilibrium than the mass of upper part(shown in blue)
> should be equal to the mass of part below it(shown in green)

What matters is the equilibrium of forces, not masses. The force of the bottom part over the element is indeed proportional to its mass ($m_bg$). But the force of the upper part over the element is not related to its (the upper part) mass.

Comment: Yeah! I got it  now. Like If I hang myself from a ceiling using a rope(holding it with hands) and then something is tied to my feet, then I would be pulling it upwards and not compressing it.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of indefinite equilibrium for a continuum reads

$\mathbf{0} = \rho \mathbf{g} + \nabla \cdot \mathbb{T}$,

being $\rho$ the density, $\mathbf{g}$ the field of volume forces, $\mathbb{T}$ the stress tensor.

If we assume a 1D model of an elastic beam in the regime of small displacement is a good model of the system, the vertical component of the equation of equilibrium can be recasted as

$0 = m g +  N'$,

being $m$ the mass per unit length of the beam, and $N$ the internal axial action, that can be written as $N = EA w'$ using the elastic constitutive law, being $EA$ the axial stiffness and $w(x)$ the axial displacement of the field.

Prescibing the boundary conditions $w(0) = 0$ and $EA w'(\ell) = 0$, we can solve the differential equation

$EA w''(z)  = -mg$

and find the solution

$w'(z) = -\dfrac{mg}{EA}(z - \ell)$
$w(z) = -\dfrac{mg}{EA}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}z^2 - \ell z \right)$

Comment: I don't know about elastic constitutive law.